# how to open a fits file in python from a different path

Tags: python

I have downloaded a fits file which is saved in the default downloads folder. But now I want to open it in python.I tried:

```
>>> from astropy.io import fits
>>> hdulist=fits.open('MOS_033.Tb.fits')
```

But that leads to an IOError:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MOS_033.Tb.fits'
```

What shall I do?

Comment: yes, it worked...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python looks into the script directory by default, not downloads folder.  Try adding full path to the file name, such as

```
hdulist=fits.open('/usr/downloads/MOS_033.Tb.fits')
```